# Edge loop not connecting and i cant edge smooth with G+G

Tags: modeling, loop, smooth

Look at this:

[image: The edge loop from the top]

[image: The edge loop from the bottom]

[image]

[image]

This is how it should be. Why are my divided like this?

So i though nevermind ill just do it my way, but i cant even edge smooth it wont let me get over the edge to smoothen it. Can someone clarify what im doing wrong?

Comment: If the loopcut can't go all around it's because it meets a ngon instead of a quad, or the face is separate, in the latter case a M >Merge by Distance should work. If it still doesn't work please share your file.